# How to stop a linear actuator?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I wrote code but the motor does not stop, it keeps moving.
Can anyone send code so that I can stop the motor after my code shown below?

```
const int forwards = 7;
const int backwards = 6;//assign relay INx pin to arduino pin

void setup() {
  pinMode(forwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
  pinMode(backwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
}

void loop() {
 digitalWrite(forwards, LOW);
 digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Activate the relay one direction, they must be different to move the motor
 delay(20000); // wait 2 seconds

 digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
 delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds
 
 digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(backwards, LOW);//Activate the relay the other direction, they must be different to move the motor
 delay(20000);// wait 2 seconds

 digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
 delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Move your code out of `loop()` (where it *loops*) and into `setup()` where it only runs once?

Comment: It's not working..

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong.

Comment: `motor does not stop` ..... what does the motor do? ...... what is it supposed to do?

Comment: you are waiting 20 seconds instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple things you can do.  Here's some examples.

1: Move code out of `loop()` and into`setup()`:

```
const int forwards = 7;
const int backwards = 6;//assign relay INx pin to arduino pin

void setup() {  
    pinMode(forwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
    pinMode(backwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output

    digitalWrite(forwards, LOW);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Activate the relay one direction, they must be different to move the motor
    delay(20000); // wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
    delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, LOW);//Activate the relay the other direction, they must be different to move the motor
    delay(20000);// wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
    delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds
}

void loop() {   
}
```

2: Stop `loop()` from looping:

```
const int forwards = 7;
const int backwards = 6;//assign relay INx pin to arduino pin

void setup() {  
    pinMode(forwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
    pinMode(backwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
}

void loop() {   

    digitalWrite(forwards, LOW);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Activate the relay one direction, they must be different to move the motor
    delay(20000); // wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
    delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, LOW);//Activate the relay the other direction, they must be different to move the motor
    delay(20000);// wait 2 seconds

    digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
    delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds

    while (1); // Stop here and do nothing forever
}
```

3: Set a "I have done it" flag:

```
const int forwards = 7;
const int backwards = 6;//assign relay INx pin to arduino pin
bool complete = false;

void setup() {  
    pinMode(forwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
    pinMode(backwards, OUTPUT);//set relay as an output
}

void loop() {   
    if (!complete) {
        digitalWrite(forwards, LOW);
        digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Activate the relay one direction, they must be different to move the motor
        delay(20000); // wait 2 seconds

        digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
        delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds

        digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backwards, LOW);//Activate the relay the other direction, they must be different to move the motor
        delay(20000);// wait 2 seconds

        digitalWrite(forwards, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(backwards, HIGH);//Deactivate both relays to brake the motor
        delay(2000);// wait 2 seconds

        complete = true;
    }
}
```

Each has benefits and drawbacks. Which is right for you depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.